Setting up an agility model and ground station contact in GMAT
I'm trying to set up a simple mission scenario where a spacecraft continually points to a ground station during periods of contact.
I believe there are three elements to accomplish this:

Identify whether ground station "sees" the spacecraft. This can be easily done by setting up a contact locator event. As far as I know, the contact locator event disregards the field of view and attitude of the spacecraft, hence the need for points 2 and 3.

Identify whether the spacecraft "sees" the ground station. This is obviously dependent on the spacecraft antenna design, but I'm not sure how to actuate it within GMAT. The closest I have found is the OpenFramesInterface sample script (samples/NeedOpenFramesInterface/Ex_R2020a_OFI_FieldOfView.script), but this appears to be
merely cosmetic?

Develop an agility model that allows the spacecraft to be continually aligned. I have so far found no resource in actuating any form of attitude control in GMAT.


Any guidance would be greatly appreciated thanks!
